# Обращение по имени

Tags: массивы, javascript, функции

Есть два массива:

```
var actions1 = {
    someFunc: function(params) {
        ...
    }
};

var actions2 = {
    goodFunc: function(params) {
        ...
    }
};
```

По AJAX запросу я получаю имя массива фукций, куда следует обратится.
В коде, как если бы было точно известно куда обращаться, я бы написал так:

```
actions2 ['goodFunc']
```

но проблема в том, что доподлинно неизвестно, какой массив должен обрабртать запрос, ответ на этот вопрос приходит вместе с самим запросом, например

```
{mode : "actions2"}
```

Как быть в таком случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужен «родительский» для `actions1` и `actions2` объект. Тогда `parent[data.mode]` даст искомый объект. Если код в теле документа, не обёрнут, тогда родитель – `window`.